# JDEE jdee-javadoc-autodoc-at-line

Tags: emacs, jdee

This is on Windows

I have the latest emacs, latest JDEE (from MELPA) and JDK1.8

If I try and call 'jdee-javadoc-autodoc-at-line' I get the error:

' Symbol's value as variable is void: working-message'

Anybody have any ideas on how to troubleshoot/fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in master, so should be shortly in MELPA.

IMHO it is better to report issues directly at [Github](https://github.com/jdee-emacs/jdee/issues), which usually results in shorter bug's live period. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll report things in GitHub in the future